# Deleting Posts on Flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I can't delete flask posts even with the correct user selected. The option to delete is only given if the user is correct but permissions are denied

My Database Models

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(50))
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    posts = db.relationship("Post", backref="user", passive_deletes=True)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    author = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False
    )
```

Deleting the Post through my route

```
@views.route("/delete-post/<id>")
@login_required
def delete_post(id):
    post = Post.query.filter_by(id=id).first()

    if not post:
        flash("Post does not exist.", category='error')
    elif current_user.id != post.id:
        flash('You do not have permission to delete this post.', category='error')
    else:
        db.session.delete(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Post deleted.', category='success')

    return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
```

The HTML Page with some python code inside for the creating and deleting the post ad

````
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %} {% block content
%}
<h1 align="center">{% block header %}Posts{% endblock %}</h1>
<div id="posts">
  {% for post in posts %}
  <div class="card border-dark">
    <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <a href="/posts/{{post.user.username}}">{{post.user.username}}</a>
      {% if user.id == post.author %}
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-sm btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
          data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        ></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="/delete-post/{{post.id}}" class="dropdown-item">Delete</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-text">{{post.text}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">{{post.date_created}}</div>
  </div>
  <br/ > {% endfor %}
</div>
{% block footer %}
<div align="center">
  <a href="/create-post"
    ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
      Create a Post
    </button></a
  >
</div>
{% endblock %} {% endblock %}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in the comparison.
You compare the two ids of user and post instead of comparing the user's id with the foreign key `post.author`.

```py
@views.route("/delete-post/<id>")
@login_required
def delete_post(id):
    post = Post.query.filter_by(id=id).first()

    if not post:
        flash("Post does not exist.", category='error')
    elif current_user.id != post.author:
        flash('You do not have permission to delete this post.', category='error')
    else:
        db.session.delete(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Post deleted.', category='success')

    return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
```